# Calling private method from inside the constructor does not change values of variables

Tags: c#, class, asynchronous, constructor

```
   public class Item
{
    public string typeid;
    public string typename;
    public string minsell;
    public string maxbuy;
    public string systemid;
    public string systemname;
    public Item(JArray jItem)
    {
        typeid = jItem[0]["all"]["forQuery"]["types"][0].ToString();
        minsell = jItem[0]["sell"]["min"].ToString();
        maxbuy = jItem[0]["buy"]["max"].ToString();
        systemid = jItem[0]["all"]["forQuery"]["systems"][0].ToString();
        GetAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("inside the constructor" + typename + " " + systemname);
    }
    public async void GetAsync()
    {
        typename = await ESIGenericRequests.GetTypeNameAsString(typeid);
        systemname = await ESIGenericRequests.GetSystemNameAsString(systemid);
        Console.WriteLine("inside the async void method" + typename + " " + systemname);
    }
}
```

I'm instantiating an Item from a json array object but there are some values absent in that json array which I want, and I can get through an async API request. Since I cannot call async methods inside my synchronous constructor I usually make (I've done the same thing in a different spot in my code and it works) an async void GetAsync() method that does it for me. The problem is that the values do not change outside of the async method. This is what it logs out:

```
inside the constructor

inside the async void methodBarghest Jita
```

Edit: This works and is pretty much the same thing:

```
    public class Character
{
    public string char_id;
    public string name;
    public string corporation_id;
    public string corporation_name;
    public string alliance_id = null;
    public string alliance_name;
    ...
    public Character(JObject _Character, Killboard _Killboard)
    { 
        ...
        GetAsync();

    }
    private async void GetAsync()
    {
        char_id = await ESIGenericRequests.ESISearch(name, "character");
        corporation_name = await ESIGenericRequests.GetCorpNameAsString(corporation_id);
        if (alliance_id != null) alliance_name = await ESIGenericRequests.GetAllianceNameAsString(alliance_id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Kindly try not to post text as a screenshot. That's not very friendly to somebody reading your question.

Comment: They *will* change - but you're not waiting for the async operation to complete. So you'll see those changes at some point in the future. It's like hitting return on a web browser address bar then immediately taking a screenshot - it's unlikely to show the web site you're trying to load...

Comment: For some reason the same worked on basically the same code:

Comment: Well whatever "basically changed" caused you to not to wait for it to finish. This is why you should not do `async void` so you can stop these kinds of problems.

Comment: Making it an async Task wouldn't allow me to call it from inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are logging before the async calls have completed. You can either use an async static factory method by making the constructor non-public and moving the async calls into the factory after the constructor is called, or add a public async initialize method that clients must call after construction. For example:

```
private async Task<Item> InitializeAsync()
{
    typename = await ESIGenericRequests.GetTypeNameAsString(typeid);
    systemname = await ESIGenericRequests.GetSystemNameAsString(systemid);
    return this;
}

public static Task<Item> CreateAsync()
{
    var ret = new Item();
    return ret.InitializeAsync();
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to block on the async calls, you can get the awaiter:

```
public void Get()
{
    typename = ESIGenericRequests.GetTypeNameAsString(typeid).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    systemname = ESIGenericRequests.GetSystemNameAsString(systemid).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Console.WriteLine("inside the formerly-async void method" + typename + " " + systemname);
}
```

Take a look at Stephen Cleary's blog post on patterns for [dealing with async and constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Comment: This solved the issue, thanks! Edit: I didn't notice you posted the code until I edited and posted mine, thanks anyway.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) post:

```
   public static async Task<Item> CreateAsync(JArray jItem)
   {
        var ret = new Item(jItem);
        ret.typename = await ESIGenericRequests.GetTypeNameAsString(ret.typeid);
        ret.systemname = await ESIGenericRequests.GetSystemNameAsString(ret.systemid);
        return ret;
    }
```

I added this method to my class, which I now instantiate with this

```
Item item = await Item.CreateAsync(jItem);
```